# How to Process Multiple Requests at the Same Time With a Server

Tags: c#, loops, tcp, client-server

Alright, so here's my thinking:

> If two requests were made to one server at the same time, would one be denied, and if so, how could you keep something like that from happening?

I currently have a server set up for a chat application I'm making, and it basically starts a TCP/IP connection, waits for a client, reads the data sent from them, sends something back, disconnects, and repeats. That way, the server never stops running, and as many requests as you want could be made.

However, what if a client was starting up while another program was using the server. If one program was getting a file from the server while the other one was starting up, and the starting up one needed data from the server, but it was already busy, what would happen?

Would the startup wait until the server was available, or would it just go straight to an error (since no connection was available). If so, this could be really bad, since then the user wouldn't have all the data, like the list of his friends, or a few chats. How could you fix this?

My idea would be that you could have a `while` loop set up so that it keeps queuing the server until it gets a response. Is this the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

No, the client should assume that the server is always available. You'll see that the basic `Socket.Listen(int32)` method (which `TcpListener` acts as a wrapper for) takes one parameter, `backlog`:

> Listen causes a connection-oriented Socket to listen for incoming connection attempts. The backlog parameter specifies the number of incoming connections that can be queued for acceptance. To determine the maximum number of connections you can specify, retrieve the MaxConnections value. Listen does not block.

Most server implementations start with something like the following:

```
socket.Listen(10); // You choose the number
while (true)
{
    var client = socket.Accept();
    // Spawn a thread (or Task if you prefer), and have that do all the work for the client
    var thread = new Thread(() => DoStuff(client));
    thread.Start();
}
```

With this implementation, there is always a thread listening for new connections. When a client connects, a new thread is created for it, so the processing for that client doesn't delay/prevent more connections from being accepted on the main thread.

Now, if a few new connections come in faster than the server can create new threads, then the new connections will be put in the backlog automatically (I think at the OS level) - the `backlog` parameter determines how many pending connections can be in the backlog at once.

What if the backlog fills up completely? At this point, you need a second server, and a load balancer to act as a middle-man, directing half the requests to the first server, and half the requests to the second server.

Answer (score 0):

Logic here is simple.

1. Server starts listening and begins accept clients.
2. Client tries to connect to the server. You can simply do nothing if server isn't running or you can implement some reconnect logic notifying client about unsuccessful connection attempts.
3. Lets assume that server was running when client tried to connect. You are talking about multi client application. You shouldn't disconnect the client. You should add connected client to the list of connected clients.
4. Then, when some of the clients connects to the server and there are some other already connected clients and sends some message. You receive that message via client socket and then you broadcast the message to all other connected clients except one that is sending the data.